# Retag and synonymize [block] ⇒ [blocks]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I came across this synonymy because [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487664/why-arent-do-end-and-always-equivalent) in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) had some using [block](/questions/tagged/block), and others using [blocks](/questions/tagged/blocks).

Block is currently more popular than blocks, but the latter would suggest slightly better that it's referring to a noun (ie a code block), rather than the verb (IO blocking CPU processing).

Comment: Ugh, what ugly unicode.  => is much more elegant, if only in a primitive sort of way.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ: Reduced to two horizontal lines, but still unicode.

Comment: Neither of those are good tags. They need to be disambiguated.

Comment: @minitech Propose a disambiguation.

Comment: I'm thinking :) What are all the possibilities? Ruby-specific blocks, code blocks, blocking operations...?

Comment: Xcode blocks? `<Blocks.h>`