# Synonymize [block] and [blocks]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retag and synonymize [block] ⇒ [blocks]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106873/retag-and-synonymize-block-blocks)

Someone [edited the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7492839/revisions) for [block](/questions/tagged/block) to say that it was a synonym of [blocks](/questions/tagged/blocks). How useless; who on Earth would approve this edit? So two things:

1. Can we synonymize these two tags?
2. There's really no "description" for this tag. I submitted an edit that kind of "describes" it (best it can). What to do? I can't just delete the edit and it wouldn't let me rollback to blank.

Comment: I posted such a description because the synonym process on Stack Overflow works at such a glacial rate. If synonyms didn't take so bloody long to get accepted, then I wouldn't have done it.