# BURNiNATE [block] and [blocks] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

So, I came across the tags [block](/questions/tagged/block) and [blocks](/questions/tagged/blocks) (total questions: x1541) just a few minutes ago, these tags hardly seem helpful, as the wiki itself points out:

> Can refer to many different things depending on the use of other tags with it.

It appears that several times, [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106873/retag-and-synonymize-block-blocks) and [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136616/merge-the-tags-block-and-blocks), they've been requested to be merged, but it's never gone through.

Because of how poorly scattered the questions with these tags are (e.g. code blocks, lambda blocks, blocks of data, hell, even [sliding blocks in a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180893/sliding-blocks-puzzle-objective-c)), I propose that we call in Troggy on this one & BURNiNATE this tag altogether.

If we decide not to burn it, then I propose we at least blacklist it, and go through and disambiguate the questions with it, to something like this:

- [css & block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+block) -> [css-block](/questions/tagged/css-block)
- [objective-c & block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block+objective-c) -> [objective-c-blocks](/questions/tagged/objective-c-blocks)
- [lambda & block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lambda+block) -> [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda)
- [magento & block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento+block) -> [magento-blocks](/questions/tagged/magento-blocks) or [magento-block](/questions/tagged/magento-block)
- [image & block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image+block) -> [image-manipulation](/questions/tagged/image-manipulation)

There are probably many other ways to disambiguate this, but those are probably the top ones in the list.

There are also questions completely unrelated to those listed above, such as blocking an IP address, amongst others.

Come on people, let's get trogdor up in here and burninate this countryside!

[TROGGY http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108400557/TROGDOR.svg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108400557/TROGDOR.svg)

Comment: Where is Trogdor?

Comment: @AndrewBarber he is in his cave. But unless you dress like a peasant, smell like a peasant, and are on fire, you cannot see his glory!

Answer (score 2):

Good idea, but it will take some time and effort.

Step 1: Synonymize [blocks](/questions/tagged/blocks) to [block](/questions/tagged/block).
(which I don't have the 5 votes in block to do)

Comment: I have two answers in blocks (score 3), and one in block (score 0), so I can't do that either.

Comment: Lance, it looks like you need to polish up on block theory

Comment: @Richard you should have the 5 points now!

Comment: @HugoDozois nope, still need 4 more votes in [tag:block]

Comment: OK, gave you one, 4 to go.

Comment: @Richard Ah crap I had upvoted for blocks instead of block

Comment: I have suggested [this synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/block/synonyms). But it needs 4 upvotes.